# Divide histogram in three parts

Tags: matlab

I want to divide the histogram in three parts and define the ranges of three parts.

```
minRed = min(red(:));
maxRed = max(red(:));
AvgRed = (minRed+maxRed)/3;
AvgRed2 = AvgRed+AvgRed;
```

But sometimes the value of `AvgRed` becomes less than `minRed` and value of `AvgRed2` exceeds the `maxRed`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you state the logic behind the division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just simple math:

Assume `minRed = 10`, and `maxRed = 100`

```
minRed = 10;
maxRed = 100;
```

You want to divide the range into three parts with equal size:
`AvgRed` should be `40`, and `AvgRed2` should be `70`.

```
%  minRed   AvgRed   AvgRed2  minRed
%  ------   ------   -------  ------
%1    10      40       70       100
%|    |        |        |        |
%     <-------------------------->
%                range

%Calculate the range:  
range = maxRed - minRed;

%Size of each part is third of the range.
thirdRange = range/3;

%Add 1/3 of range to minRed to get AvgRed (round it case value needs to be an integer).
AvgRed = minRed + round(thirdRange);

%Add 2/3 of range to minRed to get AvgRed2.
AvgRed2 = minRed + round(thirdRange*2);
```

It's simple when you draw it...